# How to check the occurrence of a date in a period

Tags: datetime, go

In my Go application, I am trying to check the occurrence of a date in a period.

```
if survey.StartPeriod.Before(time.Now()) && survey.EndPeriod.After(time.Now()) {
    fmt.Println("1 BLOCK")
}
else if survey.EndPeriod.Before(time.Now()) {
    fmt.Println("2 BLOCK")
}
```

If I have such incoming  data (current time inside period):

```
Current TIME | 2019-03-28 21:02:47.0377305 +0600 +06 m=+60.748044601
START_PERIOD | 2019-03-28 21:00:00 +0000 +0000
END_PERIOD   | 2019-03-28 21:05:00 +0000 +0000
```

I want to run code inside 1 block. My current code run that block only if I use `Before` function to both periods. I am not sure that it's correct.

If I have such incoming  data (current time outside the end_period):

```
Current TIME | 2019-03-28 21:10:47.0377305 +0600 +06 m=+60.748044601
START_PERIOD | 2019-03-28 21:00:00 +0000 +0000
END_PERIOD   | 2019-03-28 21:05:00 +0000 +0000
```

I want to run code inside 2 block. Right know it works incorrect. How to correctly make this program logic?

**EDIT**:

As you can see `CURRENT_TIME` inside range.

```
CURRENT_TIME | 2019-03-29 08:32:06.1375323 +0600 +06 m=+60.318452301
START_PERIOD | 2019-03-29 08:30:00 +0000 +0000
END_PERIOD   | 2019-03-29 08:31:00 +0000 +0000
```

When I try to test function `InTimeSpan` it return `false` value which is not correct. I am really confused. Why it happens?!

```
log.Println(InTimeSpan(survey.StartPeriod, survey.EndPeriod, time.Now()))
// return false
```

Comment: You should assign `time.Now()` to a variable, so you're checking the same time both times. As it is, your comparisons are actually different (by a few µs). Probably not a big deal in your case, but it could lead to broken results, especially for really short timespans.

Comment: Since `StartTime` and `EndTime` are parsed they have no mono clock value, so there's also a slim chance of a check that straddles a DST change causing some interesting behavior.

Comment: In your examples the Current TIME is in 2019 while both START and END periods are in 2018, so both are outside the period, maybe that's causing the unintended behavior.

Comment: Well, finally I found the reason of the problem. All time (`start_period`, `end_period`, `current_time`) I convert to UTC. In my case `time.Now().UTC()` showed time with a lag of 6 hours. For thats why I changed it to `time.Now().UTC().Add(6 * time.Hour)`. As you can see it's now elegant way. Is there any way to set timezone with UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently checking is if your **current time** is in the given range. You might want to swap `time.Now` with another time to check the occurrence of the date.

However a couple things to consider:

- make this logic to an outside function, as it needs to respond with true or false only, something like this it is as easy as:

```
func InTimeSpan(start, finish time.Time, timeToCheck time.Time) bool {
    return start.Before(timeToCheck) && finish.After(timeToCheck)
}
```

- make all times to the same timezone. Might be helpful if the timezone of the time you are checking is different, and this avoids some of the edge cases, something like this:

```
func InTimeSpan(start, finish time.Time, timeToCheck time.Time) bool {
    return start.UTC().Before(timeToCheck) && finish.UTC().After(timeToCheck)
}
```

Really lame demo: https://play.golang.org/p/rzv3coztN4Z

Comment: Hello! Can you check my post one more time please? I don't know why but it don't work. Do you have any ideas what can be the reason of the problem?

Comment: I notice that you use `UTC()` only for `start` and `finish`. I also make it as you recommended. `time.Now()` return `2019-03-29 10:22:39.1766669 +0600 +06 m=+60.516185201`.`start.UTC()` return `2019-03-29 10:20:00 +0000 UTC` and `finish.UTC()` return `2019-03-29 10:30:00 +0000 UTC`. Maybe for thats why function don't work correctly. In the same time if I use `time.Now().UTC()` it rerturn  `2019-03-29 04:22:39.1766669+0000 UTC`.

Comment: Well, finally I found the reason of the problem. All time (also current time) I convert to UTC. In my case `time.Now().UTC()` showed time with a lag of 6 hours. For thats why I changed it to `time.Now().UTC().Add(6 * time.Hour)`. As you can see it's now elegant way. Is there any way to set UTC timezone.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek you can both parse a time in a locale and parse change a time into a locale time: say if you have the date time and you want to parse it in a location you can use `time.ParseInLocation`, or when you have a time.Time struct and you want to change a different location you can check out `time.In(l Location)`: [check both here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation)

Comment: Also I believe you are parsing the start and end dates wrongly in your example. You should parse them both in the location you currently are, or everything should be in UTC